# Problem when vertical & horizontal borders of table cells have different colors

Tags: html, css

Suppose I've a table where columns are separated from each other by the use of a left white border:

```
td, th {
  &:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: 10px solid #fff;
    font-family: monospace;
  }
}
```

It looks the following:
[image]

Looks pretty nice. And now I need to separate all rows from the summary row by the use of a dark line:

```
tbody {
  tr {
    &:last-child {
      background: #EAF0F6;
      border-top: 1px solid #000;
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following picture:

[image]

The separating border becomes dotted, how to fix that?

http://jsfiddle.net/m1a530td/40/

Comment: Do you want to still keep spacing in last summary row? or just border line to be connected?

Comment: yes, I want to keep spacing and get the solid border line for the summary row

Comment: I tried it seems that you can't connect them because you use left border

Comment: You can by adding `"border: 0px none transparent;"` for the 2 last lines and adding `"box-shadow: inset -10px 0px white;"` for the last line. I can make the jsfiddle if you wish.

Comment: You could use `::after` or `::before` pseudo-selector on `.table-container` element. [Demo](https://jsbin.com/wometatosu/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use padding with a inner [`box-shadow`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#box-shadow) instead of a border to get the white space between columns and a border without gaps ([**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5q7xf1sy/1/)):

```
td, th {
  &:not(:first-child) {
    padding-left: calc(10px + 1em);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    font-family: monospace;
  }
}
```